# Python 3.4 - Class from another module causes error when used as module-level variable or class-level variable

Tags: python-3.x, import, package, global-variables, class-variables

In Python 3.4 (my OS is Ubuntu/Linux 14.04), I have a package containing many modules. Some of these modules depend on each other (module A uses objects from module B and module B uses objects from module A). I am able to manage the circular imports by putting `import Package.A` at the top of module B and `import Package.B` at the top of module A. Intra-module calls to classes from another module are performed by using the full package path to the class, such as `x = Package.A.SomeClass()`.

I run into problems in the two following situations:

**Case 1**: When a class from module A is called from module B to define a module-level variable in module B.

**Case 2**: When a class from module A is called from module B to define a class-level variable in module B.

I would like to understand why in some cases `Package.A.SomeClass()` works and in other cases it does not.

I have reproduced below a very simplified version of my code (my real code can contain dependencies from 3 or 4 modules).

**Structure of my package:**

```
/home/phodor/test.py

/home/phodor/MInventory
/home/phodor/MInventory/__init__.py (empty file)
/home/phodor/MInventory/MProducts.py
/home/phodor/MInventory/MStores.py
```

**General Case**: The following works well

/home/phodor/MInventory/MProducts.py

```
import MInventory.MStores

class MRobot():
   def __init__(self):   
      self.Price = 0
      self.Weight = 0
```

/home/phodor/MInventory/MStores.py

```
import MInventory.MProducts

class MCommercialCenterStore():    
   def __init__(self):       
      self.Name = ""
      self.CommercialCenter = ""
      self.Products = []
      self.MostSoldProduct = MInventory.MProducts.MRobot()
```

/home/phodor/test.py

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/phodor/")

from MInventory.MProducts import *
from MInventory.MStores import *

oStore = MCommercialCenterStore()
oStore.Name = "Main Street SuperCenter"
print(oStore.Name)
print(oStore.MostSoldProduct)
```

**Case 1**: The following produces an error.

/home/phodor/MInventory/MStores.py

```
import MInventory.MProducts

CustomersChoice = MInventory.MProducts.MRobot

class MCommercialCenterStore():    
    def __init__(self):       
        self.Name = ""
        self.CommercialCenter = ""
        self.Products = []
        self.MostSoldProduct = CustomersChoice
```

Error:

```
CustomersChoice = MInventory.MProducts.MRobot
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MProducts'
```

**Case 2**: The following also produces an error.

/home/phodor/MInventory/MStores.py

```
class MCommercialCenterStore():
   MostSoldProduct = MInventory.MProducts.MRobot
   def __init__(self):   
      self.Name = ""
      self.CommercialCenter = ""
      self.Products = []
```

Error:

```
MostSoldProduct = MInventory.MProducts.MRobot
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MProducts'
```

**Circular Dependency info**

As mentionned earlier on, my package contains circular dependencies. The only way to work around that so far has been to use the following statements at the beginning of my package modules:

```
import MInventory.Mproducts      ----> in the MStores module
import MInventory.MStores        ----> in the MProducts module
```

Using the following statements cause an error due to the circular dependencies:

```
from MInventory import MProducts
from MInventory import MStores

ImportError: cannot import name 'MProducts'
```

Any idea why `MInventory.MProducts.MRobot` can be called correctly in the General Case, and why it does not work when called as a module-level variable or as a class-level variable ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the Error is that python can't differ between the module name and the name of the function or class you want to use!

This problem is quite frequent, but it can appear in many different forms. Here you try to go into a file called `MInventory`. This file doesn't exist so there is no module either. This produces the problem.

It could also be that you have to import your modules in another way. Try:

```
      from MInventory import *
```

or

```
      from MInventory import (MProducts, MStores)
```

I've tryed other code examples and it worked fine with that. If it doesn't work, I've got no idea what it could be either.

Sincerely, heureka

Comment: I tried with these statements before. But by using "from MInventory import MStores" in run back into the circular dependency problem, and I get the following error: "ImportError: cannot import name 'MStores'". The only way to work around the circular dependencies in my modules is to use import MInventory.MProducts and use a full path notation, such as MInventory.MProducts.MRobot, whenever I want to call a class from MProducts. This is annoying because the full path notation works fine from within a class function, but anywhere outside of that causes the "module has no attribute" error.

Comment: So I'm afraid there is no solution I know! :-(